# eucalyptus-node-keygen.service is showing failed on node controller

Tags: eucalyptus

i have installed node controller on centos 7. And I am running command systemctl and it is showing that eucalyptus-node service is active and running but eucalyptus-node-keygen.service is failed. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The eucalyptus-node-keygen.service generates keys that are used with instance migration. The service runs conditionally to generate the keys when required, if keys are present then they do not need to be generated.

```
# systemctl cat eucalyptus-node-keygen.service | grep Condition
ConditionPathExists=|!/etc/pki/libvirt/servercert.pem
#
# stat -t /etc/pki/libvirt/servercert.pem
/etc/pki/libvirt/servercert.pem 1298 8 81a4 0 0 fd00 833392 1 0 0 1582596904 1582596904 1582596904 0 4096 system_u:object_r:cert_t:s0
```

so typically this service will show "start condition failed" which is not an error, and no action is required.